# Setting up Ubuntu 20.04 on a laptop

Tags: laptop, asus

I have an Asus Vivobook S14 with these specs:

- AMD Ryzen™ 5 4500U
- AMD Radeon R3 GPU
- 8GB RAM

What would be the best practices for setting up a fresh installation of Ubuntu?
How's battery life and temperatures on laptops with Ubuntu nowadays?
Is hibernation still problematic or battery draining?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will my device work with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/986878/will-my-device-work-with-ubuntu) Temperatures and battery life for this laptop are good.